# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runleaf method not found

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit, ant, junit4

I am getting error when run test code using ant script. But If I run testMethods using eclipse separately by **RUN AS -> JUNIT** that's return correct answer.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runLeaf(Lorg/junit/runners/model/Statement;Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
```

I am using **junit:4.12** and **spring-test:4.3.16.RELEASE** library. I have searched for solution but every solution gives answer me to use junit version greater than **junit:11**. But I am using 4.12 but still getting error.

Comment: Its been about a month since this question was posted but I just ran into the same problem. Solution for me was making sure the spring-test dependency was in the test scope along with junit.

Comment: Problem is solved. Needs to write some script at ant script.

Comment: @flopcoder - please share your piece of ant script which is solved your problem because i am facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by pom dependency. It didn't work whatever you change your junit version is because there are some other pom dependencies that introduced old junit version indirectly before load the Junit dependency that you explicitly defined in POM. To see this, enter class SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, and then enter its super class BlockJUnit4ClassRunner, you will find it doesn't lie in the junit jar package you declared in POM.

So, to solve this problem, you should find out which pom dependency indirect introduce the jar package you find in paragraph 1 through: **mvn dependency:tree**, and then use **exclusion** to exclude it in the corresponding pom dependency, such as:
`<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.org.junit</artifactId>
</exclusion>`

Now, it should work correctly! (If don't, you may need **mvn clean install**)